# How to reset google oauth 2.0 authorization?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm using [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript (Beta)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) to authorize user google account on web application (for youtube manipulations). Everything works fine, but i have no idea how to "logout" user from my application, i.e. reset access tokens.

For example, following code checks user authorization and if not, shows popup window for user to log into account and permit web-application access to user data:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false}, handleAuth);
```

But client library doesn't have methods to reset authorization.

There is [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/PCs8xXV4wxk) to redirect user to "accounts.google.com/logout", but this 
approach is not that i need: thus we logging user off from google account not only from my application, but also anywhere.

Google faq and client library description neither helpful.

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723383/google-logout-using-api-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try revoking an access token, that should revoke the actual grant so auto-approvals will stop working. I assume this will solve your issue.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke

Comment: For a JavaScript solution, see this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809339/how-to-revoke-an-authentication-token-client-side-against-the-google-api/19205371#19205371

Comment: How to revoke credentials with access token?

Answer (score 8):

Its very simple. Just revoke the access.

```
void RevokeAcess()
{
    try{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token="+ACCESS_TOKEN);
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

But it should be in asyncTask

Answer (score 7):

It depends what you mean by resetting authorization. I could think of a three ways of doing this:

1. Remove authorization on the server
   Go to myaccount.google.com/permissions, find your app and remove it. The next time you try to sign in you have to complete full authorization flow with account chooser and consent screen.
2. Sign out on the client
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
   In this way Google authorization server still remembers your app and the authorization token remains in browser storage.
3. Sign out and disconnect
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().disconnect();
   This is equivalent to (1) but on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: `gapi.auth.setToken(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for dotnet, call below API and pass the access token, doc - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke

```
        string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" + profileToken.ProfileAccessToken;
        RestClient client = new RestClient(url);

        var req = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        IRestResponse resp = client.Execute(req);
```