# Dart Google OAuth .logout()

Tags: google-api, dart

I'm using google_oauth2_client and when I call the .logout() method I clear the token from my app (plus any user info).

When I open my app up again, the Authenticate window opens up automatically logs in. Shouldn't the previous session be closed?

I am using the Chrome VM at the moment. Anyone else's thoughts on why this may be would be helpful. Possibly it is because I am logged into the browser as one account and it uses that credential?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Logout of an Application Where I Used OAuth2 To Login With Google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332/how-to-logout-of-an-application-where-i-used-oauth2-to-login-with-google)

Comment: I think this question has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909332

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646235