# Logout from youtube api v3 in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, youtube-api, windows-phone

I am using Youtube API v3 for displaying some of the videos and channels feed in my application. I use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` class to login into YouTube application using any Google account. This will give an access token after I enter proper username and password. Can anyone tell me how to logout current user? or revoke current access token? by using this api.

I have used [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/) Nuget Package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's implemented in that library but you can call an url to revoke access token:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`

More info [HERE](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

From this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649984/1173331) Question

Comment: Hi Joan, thanks for reply. Can I check whether the current token is expired or not? If expired then I can refresh it. Please provide any reference link or code if you have.

Comment: `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` method returns UserCredential object. usercredentialObject.Token has all the values you need (ExpiresInSeconds, IsExpired(),RefreshToken, etc..)