# How to Reset Non-Google Service Token

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, gmail-addons

I am trying to create a sign out functionality in my Gmail add-on.

I tried using the `resetOAuth()` function that is provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services) for Gmail add-ons, but it does not seem to reset my token and logout the third party user.

I also tried to use:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

But I am getting an `invalid_token` error.

How do I exactly use this functionality to successfully sign out my user?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to revoke access given to an application. See this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke).

> A user can revoke access by visiting [Account Settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions). It is also possible for an application to programmatically revoke the access given to it. Programmatic revocation is important in instances where a user unsubscribes or removes an application. In other words, part of the removal process can include an API request to ensure the permissions granted to the application are removed.

Check this link for additional information: [How to reset google oauth 2.0 authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646235/how-to-reset-google-oauth-2-0-authorization)

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that solution and I am getting an invalid_token error